# Association example is not executing

Tags: extjs5

I'am trying to execute the Association example present in Data binding of Kitchensink example
(http://dev.sencha.com/ext/5.0.1/examples/kitchensink/#binding-associations) in Extjs5. It works fine for me (In my app am using the Json file for my Data part).

Now am trying to move the Customer and Order model to app/model/test/Customer.js and app/model/test/Order.js and modified my dependenciew accordingly.

My Customer Grid is loading fine for me, but on clicking of record Order gris not getting loaded into memeory.

Here am pasting my Sample code for Orders.js file for refrence

Ext.define('myApp.model.test.Order', {
    extend: 'myApp.model.Base',

```
fields: [
    { name: 'date', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' },
    'shipped',
    { 
        name: 'customer',
        reference: {
            parent: 'test.Customer'
        }
    }
]
```

});

In the above file i tried with **name: 'customerId'** as well but no result :(

Did any body got the same problem? Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use a requires config somewhere to be **absolutely sure** your model classes are all loading. Also check the docs for the reference config:

http://ext5-docs.site/#!/api/Ext.data.field.Field-cfg-reference

Looks like you might want to just try:

```
{ name: 'customerId', reference: 'myApp.model.test.Customer' }
```